# Selenium: The environment you requested was unavailable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium-server, gemini

I was trying to run the test using gemini on firefox (v50.0.2), although the firefox browser opened successfully, it didn't open the url in the address bar. Then in the terminal I saw this error message:

> Cannot launch browser firefox: [init({"browserName":"firefox"})] The
>   environment you requested was unavailable.

Command:

> sudo gemini update test.js

Code:

```
module.exports = {
    rootUrl: 'http://example.com',
    gridUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

    browsers: {
        chrome: {
           desiredCapabilities: {
              browserName: 'chrome'
           }
        },
        'firefox-latest': {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: "firefox"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The test runs successfully on chrome browser. I'm running MacOSX Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was broken changes with FF driver. And wd tool doesn't support it yet. It works with firefox v46 and below.

https://github.com/gemini-testing/gemini/issues/688#issuecomment-267984936

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your firefox to 50.1.0 and test again? I got the same issue with v50.0.2, but once I updated to the latest version, I don't see that issue anymore.

Comment: After updating the firefox I'm still seeing this issue. This issue also exist on safari.